# Trying to send an email to multiple recipients in PHP using PHP mailer

Tags: php, html, mysql, email, phpmailer

I am trying to implement a send email functionality on my website. I want to be able to send an email to multiple addresses in one go. I managed to create a multi-select field on my send email form. When I select one recipient from the options, it is able to send but when I select more than one recipient it brings the error

> "2023-04-01 18:12:52 Invalid address: praisekayenda.pk@example.com,praisewalker88@example.com 2023-04-01 18:12:52 Invalid address: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address."

Below is the code I tried to use:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to_array = $_POST['to'];
    $cc  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cc']);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);

    $send_email = implode(",", $to_array);
    $subject = $title;
    $comment = $message;

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                             
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xulprojectmust@example.com';
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('xulprojectmust@example.com', 'MUST');
    foreach ($to_array as $to) {
        $mail->addAddress($to);
    }
    $mail->addReplyTo('xulprojectmust@example.com');

    // Add CC recipients
    $ccRecipients = explode(",", $cc);
    foreach ($ccRecipients as $ccRecipient) {
        $mail->addCC(trim($ccRecipient));
    }

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $comment;
    $mail->AltBody = $send_email;
    $mail->addCustomHeader("To: " . $send_email);

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        echo "<script>window.alert(\" failed to send emails $mail->ErrorInfo\")</script>";
    } else {

        echo 'Message sent';

    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could show your HTML form, or a `var_dump($_POST)` of an example submission. I'd also check what you're actually getting in `$ccRecipients` and `$ccRecipient`. The error message seems straightforward – it looks like you have an address of the shape `user@example.com,user2@example.com`, which is two addresses stuck together, and is not considered a valid single address. Separately, I have no idea why you are applying MySQL escaping to content that's not going into MySQL (at least in this code).

Comment: While it is a really bad idea to send email that way (I strongly disencourage it!), you should send the mail to one of your email addresses and add other recipients as bcc... otherwise you will expose everybodies email address to everyone (and you violate GDPR, which can mean a lot of trouble)

Comment: Looks like `$mail->addCustomHeader("To: " . $send_email);` is causing your problem. No idea why you thought that was necessary to begin with - `$send_email` is the imploded content of your `$to_array`, but you _did_ add those as recipients already with `foreach ($to_array as $to) { $mail->addAddress($to); }`